Port Forward to WireGuard on PFSense
I was using my secure PFSense router as an edge router. WireGuard was installed on PFSense so devices could join the network remotely. I have been joining my network successfully for a very long time.
Things have changed. Now I want to add a DMZ to my network. A generic PFSense router has been added as an edge router. The secure router has been placed behind the edge router. WireGuard will require my edge router to forward port 51820 to my edge router. It did not work as expected. When I try to join with WireGuard from my phone, the switch icon turns green but all of the test pings fail. This is how everything is set up
Global IP: Updated on Wireguard to reflect my new global IP
PFSense Version: 2.7.2 CE (both routers)
IP SCHEMA

Edge Router Network: 192.168.1.0/24
Edge Router Gateway: 192.168.1.1
WireGuard Router Network: 10.0.3.0/29
WireGuard Router Gateway: 10.0.3.1
WireGuard Device IP: 10.0.3.2

PORT FORWARD RULE

Interface: WAN
Address Family: IPv4
Protocol: UDP
Destination Port Range: 51820
Redirect Target IP: 10.0.3.1
Redirect Target Port: 51820

FIREWALL RULE
Set to any/any

Pinging what IP fails? What does wg on each end show?

I have pinged 1.1.1.1 to see if i have internet access. I also pinged my gateway at 10.0.3.1. Both fail. Wireguard on my phone says it’s connected but the pfsense status says my phone has never connected. Packet capture reveals that a connection on 51820 has been made on my edge router but not my secure router. This suggests that traffic is either not being routed or being dropped all together.

Wait, what is the IP of the interface on the router with WG connected to edge?

Edge WAN: dhcp. edge LAN: dhcp. Secure WAN: dhcp. Secure wg subnet: 10.0.3.1

The redirect IP should be the IP of the WG server in the LAN provided by the edge router. Not the IP of the Wireguard interface.
